# logic behind displaying time values with seconds and minutes range

Tags: php

i want to know the logic used behind displaying the time stamp like x minutes ago or x hours ago and after few hours showing the exact time like **posted at 7:57 pm** like they do it in mail sites, and also twitter etc.

how do i know when to show the seconds/minutes/hours range and when to show the actual time in am/pm format? please suggest the business logic used to achieve this.

Comment: You already know the business logic for this. You said that it should be displayed relative to now first and after a few hours display it the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the php manual:

```
<?php
function nicetime($date)
{
    if(empty($date)) {
        return "No date provided";
    }

    $periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    $now             = time();
    $unix_date         = strtotime($date);

       // check validity of date
    if(empty($unix_date)) {    
        return "Bad date";
    }

    // is it future date or past date
    if($now > $unix_date) {    
        $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense         = "ago";

    } else {
        $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense         = "from now";
    }

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    if($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }

    return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}

$date = "2009-03-04 17:45";
$result = nicetime($date); // 2 days ago

?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.time.php#89415

Comment: may i know, why has this answer been downvoted? Is it not an appropriate solution?

Comment: It will not only display 20 seconds ago, 2minutes ago but also 2 hours, 3 weeks... what you obviously don't want to?

Comment: i agree that it will display what i asked but i was wondering why downvote this answer when it is correct? someone must have thought otherwise.

Comment: the code is definitely working, I'm using it in one of my scripts :) You have to decide which answer is the best for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Print the timestamp in the regular way using PHP and use the timeago plugin for jQuery to do the fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
$time = $now - $time;

if ($time < 60) {
    $name = "second";
}
elseif ($time < 3600)
{
    $time /= 60;
    $name = "minute";
}
elseif ($time < 86400)
{
    $time /= 3600; //86400;
    $name = "hour";
}
elseif ($time < 604800)
{
    $time /= 86400; //604800;
    $name = "day";
}
elseif ($time < 31536000)
{
    $time /= 604800; //31536000;
    $name = "week";
}
else
{
    $time /= 31536000;
    $name = "year";
}
```